# копирование с преобразованием

Tags: c++, vector, stl, copy

Необходимо вызвать функцию копирования с преобразованием. С ее помощью
скопировать все элементы первого вектор во второй, где каждое значение из первого вектора
умножено на 10. Первый вектор должен остаться неизменным.

С копированием все понятно, но я не могу найти такую функцию с преобразованием в плюсах. Такая вообще есть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
vector<int> a;
...

vector<int> b(a.size());
transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),[](int x){ return x*10; });
```

Или, как вариант совсем без "своего" кода:

```
vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
vector<int> r;

transform(v.begin(),v.end(),back_inserter(r),
          bind(multiplies<int>(),placeholders::_1,10));
```

Хотя лично для меня проще и понятнее

```
vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
vector<int> r;

for(auto x: v) r.push_back(x*10);
```

Comment: ranges::transform(a, std::back_inserter(b), [](int x) { return x * 10; });